# When verify method on OpenSSL, getting an error in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, openssl, webapi

I want to do send a request to api method. But I need to verify signature. I'm using openssl. Firstly I'm creating a signature in this method;

```
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePass, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var originalData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToSign);
        using (var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey())
        {
            var signeddata = rsa.SignData(originalData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(signeddata);
        }
```

Then need to verify with this code;

```
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(ceftificatePath, "certificatePass", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);            
        var dataToVerifyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataToVerify);
        var signatureBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
        using (var rsaAlg = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PublicKey.Key)
        using (var sha256 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            return rsaAlg.VerifyData(dataToVerifyBytes, sha256, signatureBytes);
        }
```

But I'm getting error when verified.

[Verified Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUnyM.png)

Error detail is;

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACng' to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider'.

Also I'm trying this with .NET framework 4.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this post on a separate website](https://yeahexp.com/invalidcastexception-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-security-cryptography-rsacng/). It looks like your exactly question. Try to look up your question before posting it on stackoverflow next time.